Undefined ALU result value (VHDL)
Im working on this VHDL 16 bit MIPS processor, and im encountering some problems with the Execution Unit, more specifically the ALU Result. I've created a test bench individually for the ALU (which works as expected), one for the Execution Unit (which also works as expected), but when create a test bench for the entire processor connected, i get an error in the ALU, the result is undefined (the form of "000X").
This is the code i'm working with:
ALU.vhd
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL; 

entity ALU is
    Port (
    ALU_OP: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):= (others => '0');
    REG1: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
    REG2: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
    RESULT: out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    ZERO: out std_logic := '0'
    );
end ALU;

architecture Behavioral of ALU is

signal result_temp: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');

begin

    MUX: process(ALU_OP, REG1, REG2)
    begin
        if(result_temp = x"0000") then
            ZERO <= '1';
        else
            ZERO <= '0';
        end if;
    
        case ALU_OP is
            when "000" =>
                result_temp <= REG1 + REG2;
            when "001" =>
                result_temp <= REG1-REG2;
            when "010" =>
            --AND
                result_temp <= REG1 AND REG2;
            when "011" =>
            --OR
                result_temp <= REG1 OR REG2;
            when "100" =>
            --SHL 1
                result_temp <= REG1(14 downto 0)&"0";
            when "101" =>
            --SHR 1
                result_temp <= "0"&REG1(15 downto 1);
            when "110" =>
                result_temp <= REG1 XOR REG2;
            when others =>
            --NOT
                result_temp <= NOT(REG1);
        end case;
        
    end process MUX;
    RESULT <= result_temp; 
    
end Behavioral;

EXECUTION_UNIT.vhd
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL; 

entity EXECUTE_UNIT is
    Port ( PC_PLUS : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           RD1 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           RD2 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           EXT_IMMEDIATE : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           FUNC : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           --SHIFT_AMMOUNT : in STD_LOGIC;
           ALUSrc : in STD_LOGIC := '0';
           ALUOp : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           BranchAddress : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           ALU_Result : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           ZERO : out STD_LOGIC := '0');
end EXECUTE_UNIT;

architecture Behavioral of EXECUTE_UNIT is

component ALU is
    Port (
    ALU_OP: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):= (others => '0');
    REG1: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
    REG2: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
    RESULT: out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    ZERO: out std_logic := '0'
    );
end component ALU;
signal ALU_CONTROL: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):= (others => '0');
signal ALU_MUX: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
signal EXT_IMM_SH: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin
ALU_init: ALU Port map(
    ALU_OP => ALU_CONTROL,
    REG1=>RD1,
    REG2=>ALU_MUX,
    RESULT => ALU_Result,
    ZERO => ZERO
);

ALUMUX: process(ALUSrc,RD2,EXT_IMMEDIATE)
begin
    case ALUSrc is
        when '0' => ALU_MUX <= RD2;
        when others => ALU_MUX <= EXT_IMMEDIATE;
    end case;
end process;

--BranchAddress <= PC_PLUS + EXT_IMMEDIATE(13 downto 0)&"0";
EXT_IMM_SH <= EXT_IMMEDIATE(13 downto 0)&"00";

BranchAddressProcess: process(PC_PLUS, EXT_IMM_SH)
begin
    BranchAddress <= PC_PLUS + EXT_IMM_SH;
end process;

ALUControl: process(FUNC,ALUOp)
begin
    case ALUOp is
        when "000" =>
            case FUNC is
                when "000" => ALU_CONTROL <= "000";
                when "001" => ALU_CONTROL <= "001";
                when "010" => ALU_CONTROL <= "100";
                when "011" => ALU_CONTROL <= "101";
                when "100" => ALU_CONTROL <= "010";
                when "101" => ALU_CONTROL <= "011";
                when "110" => ALU_CONTROL <= "110";
                when others => ALU_CONTROL <= "111";
            end case;
        when "001" => 
            --ADDI
            ALU_CONTROL <= "000";
        when "010" => 
            --SUBI
            ALU_CONTROL <= "001";
        when "011" => 
            --LW
            ALU_CONTROL <= "000";
        when "100" => 
            --SW
            ALU_CONTROL <= "000";
        when "101" => 
            --BEQ
            ALU_CONTROL <= "001";
        when "110" => 
            --BNE
            ALU_CONTROL <= "001";
        when others => 
            --JMP
            ALU_CONTROL <= "000";
    end case;
end process;

end Behavioral;

TEST_ENVIRONMENT.vhd
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL; 

entity TEST_ENVIRONMENT_DESIGN is
    Port(
        CLOCK: in STD_LOGIC;
        REGISTER0_CONTENT: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        REGISTER1_CONTENT: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        REGISTER2_CONTENT: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        REGISTER3_CONTENT: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        REGISTER4_CONTENT: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        REGISTER5_CONTENT: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        REGISTER6_CONTENT: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        REGISTER7_CONTENT: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        INSTRUCTION_CURRENT: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        PROGRAM_COUNTER: out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0)
    );
end TEST_ENVIRONMENT_DESIGN;

architecture Behavioral of TEST_ENVIRONMENT_DESIGN is

component INSTRUCTION_FETCH is
    Port ( CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
           BRANCH_ADDRESS : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           JMP_ADDRESS : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           JMP_CTRL : in STD_LOGIC := '0';
           BRANCH_CTRL : in STD_LOGIC := '0';
           INSTRUCTION : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           NEXT_PC : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0')
           );
end component INSTRUCTION_FETCH;

component INSTRUCTION_DECODE is
    Port ( CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
           INSTRUCTION : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           WRITE_DATA : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           REGISTER_WRITE : in STD_LOGIC := '0';
           REGISTER_DESTINATION : in STD_LOGIC := '0';
           EXT_OP : in STD_LOGIC := '0';
           REG1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           REG2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           EXT_IMMEDIATE : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           FUNC : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           SHIFT_AMMOUNT : out STD_LOGIC := '0';
           reg0_cont : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
           reg1_cont : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
           reg2_cont : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
           reg3_cont : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
           reg4_cont : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
           reg5_cont : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
           reg6_cont : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
           reg7_cont : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) := (others => '0')
    );
end component INSTRUCTION_DECODE;

component EXECUTE_UNIT is
    Port ( PC_PLUS : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           RD1 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           RD2 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           EXT_IMMEDIATE : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           FUNC : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           --SHIFT_AMMOUNT : in STD_LOGIC;
           ALUSrc : in STD_LOGIC := '0';
           ALUOp : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           BranchAddress : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           ALU_Result : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           ZERO : out STD_LOGIC := '0');
end component EXECUTE_UNIT;

component MEMORY_UNIT is
    Port ( CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
           ALURes : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           RD2 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           MemWrite : in STD_LOGIC := '0';
           MemData : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0):= (others => '0')
           );
end component MEMORY_UNIT;

component MAIN_CONTROL is
    Port ( INSTRUCTION : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           RegDst : out STD_LOGIC;
           ExtOp : out STD_LOGIC;
           ALUSrc : out STD_LOGIC;
           Branch : out STD_LOGIC;
           Jump : out STD_LOGIC;
           ALUOp : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           MemWrite : out STD_LOGIC;
           MemToReg : out STD_LOGIC;
           RegWrite : out STD_LOGIC);
end component MAIN_CONTROL;

signal INSTRUCTION_sim: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
signal JMP_ADDRESS_sim: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
signal BRANCH_ADDRESS_sim: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
signal NEXT_PC_sim: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
signal DATA_WRITE: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');

signal REGISTER1_DATA: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
signal REGISTER2_DATA: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');

signal EXT_IMMEDIATE_sim: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
signal FUNC_sim: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0):= (others => '0');

signal ALURes_sim: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal ZERO_sim: std_logic :='0';
signal SHIFT_AMMOUNT_sim: STD_LOGIC;

signal READ_DATA_sim: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');

--CONTROL
signal RegDst_sim: std_logic :='0';
signal ExtOp_sim: std_logic :='0';
signal ALUSrc_sim: std_logic :='0';
signal Branch_sim: std_logic :='0';
signal Jump_sim: std_logic :='0';
signal ALUOp_sim: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):= (others => '0');
signal MemWrite_sim: std_logic :='0';
signal MemToReg_sim: std_logic :='0';
signal RegWrite_sim: std_logic :='0';
signal PCSrc: std_logic :='0';

begin

PCSrc <= Branch_sim AND ZERO_sim;
INSTRUCTION_CURRENT <= INSTRUCTION_sim;
PROGRAM_COUNTER <= NEXT_PC_sim - 1;

INSTRUCTION_FETCH_init: INSTRUCTION_FETCH Port map(
    CLK => CLOCK,
    BRANCH_ADDRESS => BRANCH_ADDRESS_sim,
    JMP_ADDRESS => JMP_ADDRESS_sim,
    JMP_CTRL => Jump_sim,
    BRANCH_CTRL => PCSrc,
    INSTRUCTION => INSTRUCTION_sim,
    NEXT_PC => NEXT_PC_sim
);

INSTRUCTION_DECODE_init: INSTRUCTION_DECODE Port map(
    CLK => CLOCK,
    INSTRUCTION => INSTRUCTION_sim,
    WRITE_DATA => DATA_WRITE,
    REGISTER_WRITE => RegWrite_sim,
    REGISTER_DESTINATION => RegDst_sim,
    EXT_OP => ExtOp_sim,
    REG1 => REGISTER1_DATA,
    REG2 => REGISTER2_DATA,
    EXT_IMMEDIATE => EXT_IMMEDIATE_sim,
    FUNC => FUNC_sim,
    SHIFT_AMMOUNT => SHIFT_AMMOUNT_sim,
    reg0_cont => REGISTER0_CONTENT,
    reg1_cont => REGISTER1_CONTENT,
    reg2_cont => REGISTER2_CONTENT,
    reg3_cont => REGISTER3_CONTENT,
    reg4_cont => REGISTER4_CONTENT,
    reg5_cont => REGISTER5_CONTENT,
    reg6_cont => REGISTER6_CONTENT,
    reg7_cont => REGISTER7_CONTENT
);

EXECUTE_UNIT_init: EXECUTE_UNIT Port map(
    PC_PLUS => NEXT_PC_sim,
    RD1 => REGISTER1_DATA,
    RD2 => REGISTER2_DATA,
    EXT_IMMEDIATE => EXT_IMMEDIATE_sim,
    FUNC => FUNC_sim,
    ALUSrc => ALUSrc_sim,
    ALUOp => ALUOp_sim,
    BranchAddress => Branch_Address_sim,
    ALU_Result => ALURes_sim,
    ZERO => ZERO_sim
);

MEMORY_UNIT_init: MEMORY_UNIT Port map(
    CLK => CLOCK,
    ALURes => ALURes_sim,
    RD2 => REGISTER2_DATA,
    MemWrite => MemWrite_sim,
    MemData => READ_DATA_sim
);

MAIN_CONTROL_init: MAIN_CONTROL Port map(
    INSTRUCTION => INSTRUCTION_sim(15 downto 13),
    RegDst => RegDst_sim,
    ExtOp => ExtOp_sim,
    ALUSrc => ALUSrc_sim,
    Branch => Branch_sim,
    Jump => Jump_sim,
    ALUOp => ALUOp_sim,
    MemWrite => MemWrite_sim,
    MemToReg => MemToReg_sim,
    RegWrite =>RegWrite_sim
);

MemoryToRegister: process(MemToReg_sim, READ_DATA_sim, REGISTER2_DATA)
begin
    case MemToReg_sim is
        when '0' => DATA_WRITE <= REGISTER2_DATA;
        when others => DATA_WRITE <= READ_DATA_sim;
    end case;
end process;
end Behavioral;

Everything compiles as it should, its just that the ALU doesnt want to calculate. I've read online that the X's appear when two instances are overwriting it, but I cant for the life of me figure out where i'm accidentally overwriting it. I've tried everything that i could think of, but given that im a begginer at FPGA's im at a comlpete loss, so anything would be helpful.
Edit with added code:
MEMORY_UNIT.vhd
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL; 

entity MEMORY_UNIT is
    Port ( CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
           ALURes : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           RD2 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
           MemWrite : in STD_LOGIC := '0';
           MemData : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0):= (others => '0')
           );
end MEMORY_UNIT;

architecture Behavioral of MEMORY_UNIT is

component RAM is
    port ( 
        CLK : in std_logic;
        WRITE_ENABLE : in std_logic;
        ADDRESS : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        WRITE_DATA : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        READ_DATA : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
    );
end component RAM;

begin

RAM_int: RAM Port map(
    CLK=>CLK,
    WRITE_ENABLE=>MemWrite,
    ADDRESS=>ALURes,
    WRITE_DATA=>RD2,
    READ_DATA=>MemData
);

end Behavioral;

RAM.vhd
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL; 

entity RAM is
    port ( 
        CLK : in std_logic;
        WRITE_ENABLE : in std_logic;
        ADDRESS : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        WRITE_DATA : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        READ_DATA : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
    );
end RAM;

architecture syn of RAM is
    type ram_type is array (0 to 63) of std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
    signal RAM_signal: ram_type := (others => (others => '0'));
    
    begin
    process (CLK)
        begin
        if CLK'event and CLK = '1' then
             if WRITE_ENABLE = '1' then
                 RAM_signal(conv_integer(ADDRESS)) <= WRITE_DATA;
             else
                 READ_DATA <= RAM_signal(conv_integer(ADDRESS));
             end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end syn;


The port ALURes of your memory_unit  is an inout, so as you do not show the source code for this module I can only guess that you do not assign 'Z' to the bits of the inout port ALURes inside memory_unit. In that case each of these bits has the value 'U'.

I've added the source code for this module. Im not sure if that is what is affecting it, but thanks for looking into it :D

Why is ALUres an inout - the address of the ram is just an in, and hence alures can just an an in

IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3.4 Signal updates "A net is a collection of drivers, signals (including ports and implicit signals), conversion functions, and resolution functions that, taken together, determine the effective and driving values of every signal on the net." This can be easier to understand from -1993/-2002  12.6.2 Propagation of signal values. To understand the problem your readers would need to understand the net topology for the signal connected to the inout port. You could provide a [mcve] while creating a minimal one can sometimes reveal the problem.

The port ALURes of MEMORY_UNIT is an inout.
This means MEMORY_UNIT is not only reading but also driving this port.
As you do not assign a value to ALURes in MEMORY_UNIT
(ALURes is only read by RAM) the driving value at all bits of ALURes
in MEMORY_UNIT is 'U' by default. To fix the problem you can change the
port ALURes to "in", or you can assign ALURes <= (others => 'Z'); in MEMORY_UNIT.
